# Can the magnitude of the electric field or magnetic field in a plane electromagnetic wave be equal to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I have tried reading related questions on here, but I have not found what I perceive to be my question nor the answer I seek. Every place I look (textbooks, here, Quora, etc...) indicates that $E_0/B_0 = \omega/k = E/B = c$. Since $E_0$ and $B_0$ are the amplitudes, they are not zero. Since $\omega = 2 \pi f$ and $k = 2\pi / \lambda$, they are not zero. However, $E$ and $B$ are the magnitudes of the electric and magnetic fields.

My understanding is that, at certain instants, these CAN BE zero. If they can be, how can $E/B = c$ at ALL times? A certain textbook even explicitly states that for EM radiation for which $E$ and $B$ are in-phase, $E$ and $B$ reach their maximum, minimum, AND ZEROS and the same points. Clearly, I am wrong somewhere. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand how to write $E$ in terms of $E_0$, $k$, and $\omega$, and similarly for $B$? There should be a sine or cosine in there.

Comment: Are you worried about taking the limit of $E/B$ as the numerator and denominator both go to zero?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ghoster Yes.  I know the functions for E and B.  I knew them before Gabriel posted them below.  I am worried that the value of E and B are both zero when the functions cross the x-axis and, thus, E/B does not equal c at those points.  Your second comment implies to me that L'Hospital's rule might apply.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: It’s no different from $x/x$.

Comment: @Ghoster As stated below to Gabriel, I can now accept that simple division of the two functions (Ey/Bz) will cancel the cos functions, leaving Ey/Bz = E0/B0 = c. However, I now am stuck, as you stated above, on the calculus of taking the limit of E/B as the numerator and denominator both go to zero. This is a calculus Q I must explore.  As mentioned below, L'Hospital's rule is for one-variable functions (at least in any common application that I have ever seen).  Our functions here depend on x and t. 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let your EM plane waves be described by
$$
E_y(x,t) = E_0 \cos (\omega t - kx) \quad\quad B_z(x,t) = B_0 \cos (\omega t -kx),
$$
then we have that $\dfrac{E_y}{B_z} = \dfrac{E_0}{B_0} = c$ at all times. (Check as an exercise that these satisfy Maxwell's equations, and that I didn't mess up any signs!.)

You might wonder what happens in the lines
$$
\omega t - kx = \pi (n + 1/2),\quad \text{for which} \quad \cos(\omega t - kx) = 0.
$$ Here clearly you can see that, in the limit, we still have $\dfrac{E_y}{B_z} = \dfrac{E_0}{B_0} = c$. One way to do this is through Taylor expanding around $\pi (n + 1/2)$ (or equivalently by applying l'Hôpital's rule), but I don't thing you need such "sophisticated math". (Check this also!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I fully agree that E0/B0 = c.  These are the amplitudes.  They are never zero.  My issue is that, at ANY point, E/B = c.  Here, E and B are magnitudes.  They CAN be zero.  So, I can't understand how to show that E/B = c at a point where E = B =0.

Comment: Joe, that's precisely what I discuss at the second part of the question, when I talk about the case $\omega t - kx \to \pi (n+q/2)$. Just Taylor expand or use l'Hôpital's rule to see everything is ok! But you don't even have to do that, you just have $cos(\omega t - kx)/cos(\omega t - kx) = 1$.

Comment: Gabriel, you are saying to just divide the functions Ey/Bz and the cosines cancel, leaving only E0/B0 = Ey/Bz = c. (I didn't use y and z subscripts for the magnitudes.) I can accept that! I guess I have now trapped myself in the calculus. If we evaluate Ey and Bz separately at a point where they are zero, and divide them, we get 0/0.  You mentioned sophisticated math above.  Apparently, this is what is needed to show that the limits of the numerator and denominator, which both go to zero, lead us to c. But, to my knowledge, L'Hospital's rule applies to single variable functions only. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's true that $E$ and $B$ depend on two variables, so you might have to get creative about how to use l'Hôpital. But note that the function only cares about the difference between $\omega t$ and $kz$. So I guess you can treat $\omega t - kz$ as a variable (i.e. you do a change of variable), and you study its limit. I hope this clears everything out!